# boolean function returning false even though condition is satisfied to return true in c++. Why?

Tags: c++, for-loop, boolean, return-value

My function is a simple palindrome algorithm that is supposed to take an input integer (test), turn it into a string (test_s), then reverse that string in a new variable (test_s_reverse) then return true if test_s is equal to test_s_reverse.

```
bool is_palindrome(int test){
    test_s = to_string(test);
    test_length = test_s.length();
    for (int i=(test_length + 1); i>=0; i--){
        test_s_reverse += test_s[i];
    }
    if (test_s_reverse == test_s){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I created a main function to test results and using input 12321 the program returns false, even though cout for test_s_reverse is = 12321 and test_s = 12321.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `test_s[i]` to `test_s.at(i)` to enable bounds checking.

Comment: So it works as C++ code, but using it in (undisclosed syntactically similar) language it doesn't?

Comment: `test_length + 1` ?

Comment: Where are all your declarations? If these are all globals, `test_s_reverse` is never getting reset, so only the first call could possibly work. Also, `i` is being initialized to an illegal index...

Comment: Tactical note: Don't waste your time reversing. Compare the first and last characters. If they match, compare the second and second last characters. Keep marching inward and comparing until you hit the center. If you make it, to the center return true. If any of the compares don't match, return false.

Comment: The first two iterations of the loop each have undefined behaviour due to accessing `test_s[test_s.length() + 1]` and `test_s[test_s.length()]` respectively.   Valid indices for `test_s` are `0` to `test_s.length() - 1`.   Also (more pedantically), strings indices are an unsigned type (`std::size_t`, typically) and may have values larger than an `int` can represent.

Comment: @Peter in C++11 and later, `length` is a valid index, it is a reference to a `'\0'` character (either the null terminator if the string is not empty, otherwise a static `char` in memory). So, accessing `test_s[test_s.length()]` is not UB anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `test_length - 1` instead of `test_lenght + 1`, because in the new reversed string you have some extra characters which you can't see if you print them.

The `.length()` function returns you exactly the number of characters in the string. So you either go with `test_length`, but you do `i>0`, or if you go in the loop with `i>=0` you go with `test_length - 1`, so you will be sure that there are no blank characters at the end of new string.

But, if you start with `test_length`, you will need to edit, since there is no character at `test_length` position:

```
test_s_reverse += test_s[i-1];
```

If you use pure C++ code, it should look like this:

```
bool is_palindrome(int test){
    string test_s = to_string(test);
    int test_length = test_s.length();
    string test_s_reverse;
    for (int i=(test_length); i>0; i--){
        test_s_reverse += test_s[i-1];
    }
    if (test_s_reverse == test_s){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were up to me, I'd do the job rather differently.

`std::string` has a constructor to build a string for a pair of iterators. It also supports reverse iterators. As such, you can construct a reversed string a bit more easily like this:

```
std::string test_s_reversed(test_s.rbegin(), test_s.rend());
```

...but given how much that simplifies the task, you can boil most of it down to something like this:

```cpp
bool is_palindrome(std::string const &s) { 
    return s == std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
}
```

Implementation for an integer would then be something like this:

```cpp
bool is_palindrome(int val) {
    return is_palindrome(std::to_string(val));
}
```